# How to receive HTTP Response

Tags: c, sockets, http, networking

```
char url[]= "GET " PATH "\r\n"
"Host: " HOST "\r\n"
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n"
"\r\n";    
write(sfd, url, strlen(url)); // write(fd, char[]*, len);  
bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
while(read(sfd, buffer, 1024 - 1) != 0){
    printf("%s", BUFFER_SIZE);
    bzero(buffer, 1024);
}
```

Result:
[image]

I'm writing a HTTP Client using Socket. The problem here is the read() func only return HTTP respond body. But i want it to fetch http respond header also. I don't know what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What are `buffer` and `BUFFER_SIZE`?

Comment: Using `BUFFER_SIZE` as name of buffer is very confusing, so you shouldn't do that.

Comment: `write(sfd, header, strlen(url))`? What if `header` contains more data than `url`? Or what if it's shorter?

Comment: i edited the code, sorry everybody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not specifying an HTTP version in the `GET` request, so the server will think you are a pre-1.0 client and won't send any headers to you.

Do this instead:

```
char url[]= "GET " PATH " HTTP/1.0\r\n" ...
```

Or:

```
char url[]= "GET " PATH " HTTP/1.1\r\n" ...
```

And then the server will give you headers.